# HTML file path is coming in the Email body instead of HTML file content in Jenkins using Email-ext

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I am giving the below option in Jenkins,

Post-build Actions:

Content Type: HTML (text/html)

Default Subject: $DEFAULT_SUBJECT

Default Content: ${FILE,path="c:/aaa/bbb/ccc/report.html”}

But if I check the email received via jenkins, its showing the file path in the email body as '${FILE,path="c:/aaa/bbb/ccc/report.html”}' instead of actually displaying the content inside the HTML file